# Cannot force push to main branch using GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

Error:

```
! [remote rejected]     main -> main (refusing to allow a GitHub App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/docker.yml` without `workflows` permission)
```

After researching a bit, I learnt that I need to give it the necessary permissions. I have no idea from where and how can I grant it the permission. I don't have much experience either.

How should I fix this error? This is being caused because I'm forcing my changes to the repo since normal pushes are being rejected.

I'm very well aware that I should not be using `--force` in the first place. Since I need to push them, I'm obligated to do so. I pull from main before pushing, it causes conflicts that needs to be resolved manually which I don't want to.
If there's any work around, I'm happy to implement that as well.

Code:

```
name: Update Fork

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 10 * * *' # runs every everyday at 10:00

jobs:
  update_fork:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout Forked Repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: username/repo_name
        ref: main

    - name: Setup Git
      run: git config --global user.email ${{ secrets.EMAIL }} && git config --global user.name user_name

    - name: Check for Upstream Changes
      run: |
        git remote add upstream https://github.com/upstream_user_name/upstream_repo

        upstream_commit=$(git ls-remote --heads upstream | grep main | awk '{print $1}')
        # forked_commit=$(git rev-list --max-count=1 HEAD)
        forked_commit=$(git log -n 10 --pretty=%H)

        # if git rev-list $forked_commit..HEAD | grep -q $upstream_commit; then
        if echo "$forked_commits" | grep -q "$upstream_commit"; then
          echo "No commits to be synced!"
        else
          git fetch upstream
          git pull --rebase -X ours upstream main
          git push -f origin main

          echo "Rebase successful!"
        fi
```

After this code failed to push commits, I added below code:

```
      with:
        repository: username/repo_name
        ref: main
        repo-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This didn't fix the issue either. And I'm pretty sure this was wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error it looks like your git user does not have access to update workflows.

There doesn't appear to be an explicitly defined `workflows` permission, but there is an OAuth scope for [workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps).

Try adding this [permission](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#permissions) to your workflow.

```yaml
permissions:
  actions: write
```

If that doesn't work, try this, I have needed to add this before to a workflow that was committing back to the repo.

```yaml
permissions:
  contents: write
```

Comment: why using `rebase` requires me to use `-f` at the time of push? What can be done to avoid it? Since I want to be up-to-date  with the upstream repo, and I've made a ton of changes in my repo, I want them to preserved.

Comment: Whenever git history is changed you must use a force push. If you want to avoid rebasing then you should do a merge commit. This will not modify your history, but add merge commit pulling in changes from upstream

Comment: I'm able to do them manually, but the same commands show conflicts when run on GH Actions.. :/. And yes, `contents: write` did help a few times. However, I had to workflow permissions as read/write instead of read only in repo settings..